# find and replace with variables

Tags: variables, sed

I'm trying to find and replace with variables, but it doesn't work.

Here is the code. I need to append `-C -w 10% -c 5% -p /u0` to append to the end of a matching line. I do not know how to suppress the (-) Any ideas?  Thank you.

```
OLD=$(command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -p / -p /var -p /tmp -p /home -p /boot -p /usr -A -e)
NEW=$(command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -p / -p /var -p /tmp -p /home -p /boot -p /usr -A -e -C -w 10% -c 5% -p /u0)

sed -i "s/$OLD/$NEW/" /home/scripts/nrpe.cfg
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking. Your `OLD=$(...)` and `NEW=$(...)` commands cannot work, because they will consider `command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk` an environment variable assignment, and will then try to execute `-w ...` as a command.)

Comment: I will just need to replace the variable "old" with "new" one line with another one.  Thanks

Comment: Because the commands inside `$(...)` invariably fail, both `$OLD` and `$NEW` will be _empty_ when your `sed` command is reached (unless `set -e` is in effect, in which case the script  will abort after the `OLD=...`  command).

Comment: If the strings inside `$(...)` are just that - _mere strings_ - then assign them as follows: `OLD='command[check_Disk]=...'` - i.e., use _single quotes_ to delimit them (`$(...)`, by contrast, _executes_ the enclosed string and replaces `$(...)` with the _output_ produced).

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I still getting errors. sed: -e expression #1, char 0: no previous regular expression

Comment: You need to _escape_ both the old and the new string before passing it to `sed` - see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (assumes `bash`):

```
OLD='command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -p / -p /var -p /tmp -p /home -p /boot -p /usr -A -e'
NEW='command[check_disk]=/usr/local/nagios/libexec/check_disk -w 10% -c 5% -p / -p /var -p /tmp -p /home -p /boot -p /usr -A -e -C -w 10% -c 5% -p /u0'

oldEscaped=$(sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$OLD")
newEscaped=$(sed 's/[\\&/]/\\&/g' <<<"$NEW")

sed -i "s/$oldEscaped/$newEscaped/" /home/scripts/nrpe.cfg
```

- Your first problem was that **you mistook `$(...)` for a string-quoting mechanism** (it is not; it's used for [command substitution](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution) (executing the enclosed command and replacing the construct with the command's output)).
  To assign literal strings, simply use *single quotes* as above.
- Your second problem was that **you can't blindly pass strings to `sed`'s `s` (string-substitution) command**, because certain characters have special meaning to `sed`, so to use them *literally* **they have to be *escaped*** - the most obvious problem being the `/` instances in the strings, which get mistaken for the delimiters of the `s/.../.../` command.

  - Therefore, 2 auxiliary `sed` commands are used to perform the requisite escaping:

    - `sed 's/[^^]/[&]/g; s/\^/\\^/g' <<<"$OLD"` escapes the *old* string so that none of its characters can be mistaken for the regex delimiter or special regular-expression characters.
    - `sed 's/[\\&/]/\\&/g' <<<"$NEW"` escapes the *new* string so that none of its characters  can be mistaken for the regex delimiter or backreferences (such as `&`, or `\1`).

Finally, note that it's better *not* to use all-uppercase *shell* variable names such as `$OLD`, so as to avoid conflicts with *environment* variables.

Comment: Thanks a lot mklement0 it works. I learn something new today.